# How to prove that gcd of following is always 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given: $p-1= 4n-2$ where n is a natural number and p is prime number.

Let,
$$a=1+2^{(p-1)/2}+2^{(p+1)/4}$$
$$b=1+2^{(p-1)/2}-2^{(p+1)/4}$$
Then prove that,
$$gcd(a,b)=1$$
If,
$3 | p-1$ and 10,13 does not divides $p-1$.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m=2^{(p-3)/4}$, then $a=2m^2+2m+1$ and $b=2m^2-2m+1$. The Euclidean algorithm gives
\begin{align*}
\gcd(a,b) &= \gcd(2m^2+2m-1,2m^2-2m+1) \\
&= \gcd\big((2m^2+2m+1)-(2m^2-2m+1),2m^2-2m+1\big) \\
&= \gcd(4m,2m^2-2m+1).
\end{align*}
But $2m^2-2m+1$ is odd, so
\begin{align*}
\gcd(a,b) &= \gcd(4m,2m^2-2m+1) \\
&= \gcd(m,2m^2-2m+1) \\
&= \gcd\big(m,(2m^2-2m+1)-m(2m-2)\big) \\
&= \gcd(m,1)=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\mathrm{gcd} \, (a,b) = \mathrm{gcd} \, (a,a-b).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much